# application:didReceiveLocalNotification: not called when app in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uilocalnotification

When my app goes in background then  **applicationDidEnterBackground** is automatically called and in this method we fire local notification. but **didReceiveLocalNotification**: method is not called

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
localNotification.alertBody = textString;
localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber =  1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
}
```

Comment: UILocalNotification *launchNote = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (launchNote){ have to work

Comment: please check with real device.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:

Answer (score 5):

Your expectations with local notifications are incorrect:

When your app will go in background then you will see an immediate notification on your phone but you have to tap that notification to trigger didReceiveLocalNotification delegate.

If you receive local notification in foreground then didReceiveLocalNotification will be triggered automatically.

Above scenario is tested and verified.

Update: You must read this documentation:
http://www.thekspace.com/home/component/content/article/62-uilocalnotification-demystified.html

Comment: i am not getting any badges or banner when local notification is fired .and off course we can expect local notification in this this scenario because app in inactive mode not suspended.

Comment: Wow I copy pasted your same code and I got instant local notification. @Downvoter: Please care to comment.

Comment: @Tariq : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification: and read its discusstion part

Comment: @RahulSharma Please check your code with this documentation. I have copy pasted your code and everything is working great. So probably you have ignore some other pieces http://www.thekspace.com/home/component/content/article/62-uilocalnotification-demystified.html

Comment: @NitinGohel Not sure what you're confused about. didFinish will be only called if you're launching the app if the app is not running. Check any documentation on internet or stackoverflow.

Comment: @Tariq: it is working on simulator but not in real device with ios7.0

Comment: @RahulSharma Sorry mate code worked in my iphone 6 8.1.3... So issue is not related with your code. Would encourage you to try some samples and test it on your device. If sample fails in your device then check device settings or try in other device. If it worked then match your source code with sample. You will find tons of sample on UILocalNotification. Here is the one I have found http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=292

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
NSDate *pickerDate = [date_picker date];
// Schedule the notification
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Alert Body Message";
localNotification.alertAction = @"Alert Action Message";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]     scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

and use this code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in App delegate class.

```
    UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (locationNotification) {
    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose having your code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ? This will never get called if you go to background and come in foreground.

Comment: @Tariq that called when you application in background mode and you got notificaiton . when you click on app icon or notification this method going to be called

Comment: @NitinGohel Which method will be called ? OmPrakash said if your app is in background and you tap notification then didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will be called. Double check ios documentation. didFinish is only get called when app launched first time. When you tap notification in background mode (not terminated mode)didReceiveLocalNotification method will be called not didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: application launch with option called when app is launch first . it is not called when app in background

Comment: @RahulSharma, i provided snippet for yoy goal, it's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Before scheluding notification you must register it for specified type:

```
    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    localNotification.alertBody = textString;
    localNotification.alertAction = @"View";
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber =  1;
    // register notification settings
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
  UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
      |UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
      |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
  [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
#endif
} else {
  UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
  [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
}

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
    }
```

Comment: @RahulSharma, i add handler for version under 8.0. Now it must work